# Java's AtomicLong implementation loops

Tags: java, loops, atomic

So I was using `AtomicLong` and decided to have a look at its implementation, and noticed the following difference between 2 methods:

`getAndAdd(long delta)`:

```
public final long getAndAdd(long delta) {
    while (true) {
        long current = get();
        long next = current + delta;
        if (compareAndSet(current, next))
            return current;
    }
}
```

`incrementAndGet()`:

```
public final long incrementAndGet() {
    for (;;) {
        long current = get();
        long next = current + 1;
        if (compareAndSet(current, next))
            return next;
    }
}
```

What struck me as odd is that both methods do almost exactly the same thing, but they were implemented using 2 different loops; a `while` in the first and a `for` in the second. As far as I can tell this would make no difference in performance. Is there a specific reason for this?

Comment: I think the reason is that different developers where involved. But both loops are exactly the same.

Comment: I don't even see why they wouldn't compile to the same bytecode, either. I would need to test this to be sure, but I would expect that `while(true)` and `for(;;)` produce the same bytecode output. The only thing I can think of is @Stephan's suggestion of different developers, but I don't know how you'd prove or disprove that without access to the version control history for the file.

Comment: @Stephan & @Thomas: I had considered the possibility, but in the JDK6 source code I can only see Doug Lea as the `@author`, which made me extra curious as to why this has been implemented the way it was. Maybe Doug is just playing with us.

Comment: I'm e-mailing Doug right now to ask the question. We must know.

Comment: @Stephan was apparently right. After asking the man himself, he replied that he prefers the `for(;;) {}` syntax, but in this case he was collaborating with other people who apparently preferred the `while(true) {}` syntax.

Comment: @pHk You should post that as an answer and accept that instead of the currently selected answer. Paste quotes right from the email.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After asking the original author about why this was implemented in this way, this is what he replied:

> I always use "for(;;)" (pronounced "forever"),
>   except when collaborating (in this case with
>   JVM folks) who for some stupid reason prefer "while(true)".

To summarize: there is no difference between `for(;;) {}` and `while(true) {}` and the reason why both are used interchangeably in `AtomicLong` is because different authors preferred different syntaxes.

Answer (score 3):

No, there are just two ways of expressing infinite loop in Java. None is universally belived to be better.

Comment: +1: Plus `do { /* */ } while(true);`  Actually there is an infinite number of possible implementations of an infinite loop. ;)

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check the produced bytecode. I wouldn't be surprised if it is identical.

Maybe they are from different authors, or different moods... When I write lots of for loops, I'd probably go with the `for(;;) {` syntax, when speding too much time writing while loops, I'd use `while(true) {`.

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference between `while(true)` and `for(;;)`, both should produce the same bytecode (you can check this with javap). Some might say that you should use `while(true)` since `for(;;)` might confuse beginners, however that is more a matter of style.